# Why does gVim move } at the beginning of the line in insert mode?

Tags: vim

I was editing a CSS file with gVim on Windows 7 when I realized every time I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd> in insert mode as the 4th character of a line, it is put as the 1st one. For example, if the cursor is at the end of line 31 (see below)

[image: Initial Situation]

and I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, gVim inserts a new line and positions the cursor at the 4th column as follows:

[image: After hitting Enter]

Here's when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd> and `}` is moved to the 1st column:

[image: After hitting }]

Why does gVim behave in such a way? And how could I fix it?

Comment: This may be better suited for the vi/vim SE site.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is perfectly normal and expected so there is *nothing* to fix.

It is defined in `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/css.vim`:

```
setlocal indentkeys=0{,0},!^F,o,O
```

See `:help 'indentkeys'`.